Using dplyr to calculate change from baseline with multiple colums as values
I am struggling to find an R function that will convert my data into "fold changes from baseline values". Basically I have a data.frame consisting of subject.id and timepoints grouped by treatments with multiple species values as follows:
subject.id  timepoint  treatment  Species1  Species2  Species3  SpeciesX 
id1          baseline        A          0         10         5          5
id1             2h           A          99         12         5          6
id1             4h           A          40         20         6          5
id2          baseline        B          50         10         5          5
id2             2h           B          100        20         5          6
id2             4h           B          200        20         6          5

I need something like this keeping the same species names but with fold changes:
subject.id  timepoint   treatment  Species1  Species2  Species3  SpeciesX 
id1          baseline        A          1         1         1           1
id1             2h           A          err      1.2       1           1.2
id1             4h           A          1         2         1.2         1
id2          baseline        B          1         1         1           1
id2             2h           B          2         2         1           1.2
id2             4h           B          4         2         1.2         1


df |> mutate(across(Species1:SpeciesX, ~.x / .x[timepoint == "baseline"]), .by = c(subject.id, treatment))?

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(subject.id, treatment) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Species"), ~.x/.x[timepoint == "baseline"]))

# A tibble: 6 × 7
# Groups:   subject.id, treatment [2]
  subject.id timepoint treatment Species1 Species2 Species3 SpeciesX
  <chr>      <chr>     <chr>        <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 id1        baseline  A             1         1        1        1  
2 id1        2h        A             1.02      1.2      1        1.2
3 id1        4h        A             1         2        1.2      1  
4 id2        baseline  B             1         1        1        1  
5 id2        2h        B             2         2        1        1.2
6 id2        4h        B             4         2        1.2      1  

Selecting by position:
> df %>% 
    mutate(across(c(4:7)-2, ~.x/.x[timepoint == "baseline"]), .by = c(subject.id, treatment))
  subject.id timepoint treatment Species1 Species2 Species3 SpeciesX
1        id1  baseline         A    1.000      1.0      1.0      1.0
2        id1        2h         A    1.025      1.2      1.0      1.2
3        id1        4h         A    1.000      2.0      1.2      1.0
4        id2  baseline         B    1.000      1.0      1.0      1.0
5        id2        2h         B    2.000      2.0      1.0      1.2
6        id2        4h         B    4.000      2.0      1.2      1.0


Thank you so much! My only problem is that Species columns have different names, they do not start with Species :(

If Species refers only to numeric variables, then you can try: df %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~.x/.x[timepoint == "baseline"]), .by = c(subject.id, treatment)), if not, give some example for we to better help you.

Species are not the only numeric columns, but it is a range of columns from 4:30 as an example. Could you help?

Thank you for the quick answer, I get an error now: Caused by error in across():
! Can't compute column `4'

@pepe84 could you update your question with a more representative data frame? One that more closely resembles your structure and column names. You would get more exact help that way.

@LMc one of my data point (denominator) had a zero, I have updated it above. When computing the fold changes could it be the cause of the error?

Consider using integer position like this: df %>%    mutate(across(c(4:30)-2, ~.x/.x[timepoint == "baseline"]), .by = c(subject.id, treatment)) . . You can even write the name of variables in those positions separated by : as in @Jon Spring comment and it'll work too.

@JilberUrbina many thanks. I am now getting a new error saying: Error in mutate():
ℹ In argument: across((4:30)-2, ~.x/.x[timepoint == "baseline"]).
Caused by error in across():
! Can't compute column Species1.
Caused by error in dplyr_internal_error():
Run rlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred.

you are missing c() in across(c(4:30)-2..

@JilberUrbina same error after adding c( ). Not sure what is happening.

If you also want to consider base R, using split
grp <- c("subject.id", "treatment")
rng_1 <- 1:3 # names and group
rng_2 <- 4:7 # values to calculate with

data.frame(df[,rng_1], 
  do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, paste(df[,grp[1]], df[,grp[2]])), \(lst) 
    setNames(data.frame(sapply(rng_2, \(cols) 
      lst[,cols] / lst[grep("baseline", lst$timepoint), cols])), 
        names(df[rng_2])))), row.names=NULL)
  subject.id timepoint treatment Species1 Species2 Species3 SpeciesX
1        id1  baseline         A      NaN      1.0      1.0      1.0
2        id1        2h         A      Inf      1.2      1.0      1.2
3        id1        4h         A      Inf      2.0      1.2      1.0
4        id2  baseline         B        1      1.0      1.0      1.0
5        id2        2h         B        2      2.0      1.0      1.2
6        id2        4h         B        4      2.0      1.2      1.0

With dplyr using the index
df %>% mutate(across((4:7) - 2, ~ .x / .x[1]), .by = c(subject.id, treatment))
  subject.id timepoint treatment Species1 Species2 Species3 SpeciesX
1        id1  baseline         A      NaN      1.0      1.0      1.0
2        id1        2h         A      Inf      1.2      1.0      1.2
3        id1        4h         A      Inf      2.0      1.2      1.0
4        id2  baseline         B        1      1.0      1.0      1.0
5        id2        2h         B        2      2.0      1.0      1.2
6        id2        4h         B        4      2.0      1.2      1.0

Note that the number of groups is subtracted from the indices (see here)
